# json.net get all json tokens and readout specific properties

Tags: .net, json, token, json-deserialization

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "GuiElement0": {
    "gHeight": "50",
    "gID": "0",
    "gY": "80"
  },
  "GuiElement1": {
    "gFile": "",
    "gID": "0",
    "gStyle": "2",
    "gX": "130",
    "gY": "240"
  },
  "GuiElement2": {
    "gThickness": "1",
    "gID": "0",
    "gStyle": "3",
    "gX": "150",
    "gY": "20"
  }
}
```

Now i would like to iterate through the single elements like this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(file.ReadToEnd());
foreach (JToken token in json.Children())
{
    if(JObject.Parse(token.ToString()).GetValue("gID").ToString() == "0" )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(JObject.Parse(token.ToString()).Property("gID").ToString());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected. 
My goal is to readout the gID for each token and then to process each of the elements seperatley.

If i have got the ID, then i will dezerialize the json

```
"gThickness": "1",
"gID": "0",
"gStyle": "3",
"gX": "150",
"gY": "20"
```

like this:

```
(GuiElement)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GuiBar>(token.ToString());
```

It would be great if someone could point me to my mistake. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
foreach (JProperty prop in json.Children())
{

    JToken value = prop.Value;
    if(value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((JObject)value).GetValue("gID").ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, `token` takes values of child json properties. For example, on first iteration it will be a `GuiElement0` property:

```
"GuiElement0": {
    "gHeight": "50",
    "gID": "0",
    "gY": "80"
}
```

You can't call `JObject.Parse()` on such property because it's not a valid JSON (it's just a part of it).

Anyway, it's not a good idea to have multiple parses of the same JSON or its parts, such solution will have very poor performance. Instead just cast iterated childrens to `JProperty` and access current element through `JProperty.Value`:

```
foreach (JProperty currProperty in json.Children().OfType<JProperty>())
{
    JToken currElement = currProperty.Value;
    // ...
```

Here `currElement` will take the value of `GuiElement` property:

```
{
    "gHeight": "50",
    "gID": "0",
    "gY": "80"
}
```

You could access specific sub-properties for comparing via `JToken.SelectToken()`. I also suggest using strongly typed `JToken.Value<T>` property for extracting the values:

```
JToken gIdValue = currElement.SelectToken("gID");
if (gIdValue.Value<int>() == 0)
{
  // ...
```

And finally, you could deserialize the object with `JToken.ToObject<T>()` call This will avoid additional JSON parsing.

Here is the final code:

```
foreach (JProperty currProperty in json.Children().OfType<JProperty>())
{
    JToken currElement = currProperty.Value;
    JToken gIdValue = currElement.SelectToken("gID");
    if (gIdValue.Value<int>() == 0)
    {
        var bar = currElement.ToObject<GuiBar>();
    }
}
```